# LINQ to Entities select all entries in many-to-many relationship

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework, collections, linq-to-entities

I have 3 MySql tables: `Students`, `Classes` and `StudentsInClasses`.

The Entity Framework translates these into two entities `Student` and `Class`, each linking to the other with a many-to-many navigation property (e.g. `Student.Classes`).

But there is no `StudentsInClasses` entity, so **what's the best way to call, using LINQ to Entities, the equivalent of SQL**:

```
SELECT StudentId, ClassId FROM StudentsInClasses;
```

I'm looking for a HashSet (or equivalent) of { StudentId, ClassId } pairs so I can quickly look up whether a given student is in a given class. (What's the best way of storing this?)

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
var query = from @class in db.Classes
            from student in @class.Students
            select new { ClassId = @class.ID, Student = student };

var lookup = query.ToLookup(x => x.ClassId,
                            x => x.Student);
```

(I suspect a `Lookup` is more appropriate than a `HashSet` here.)

EDIT: If you don't want to use query expressions:

```
var query = db.Classes
              .SelectMany(@class => @class.Students,
                          (@class, student) => new { ClassId = @class.ID,
                                                     Student = student });
```

Comment: Thanks! Out of interest, how would I write that using `db.Classes.Select(...)` form?

Comment: Cheers. And then is the most efficient check `lookup[someKey].Contains(someValue)`?