# LINQ to Entities delete all entries in many-to-many relationship

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I asked a [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7800332/linq-to-entities-select-all-entries-in-many-to-many-relationship) earlier today, so you might get a bit of deja vu, but I'm afraid I can't work this one out.

I have 3 MySql tables: `Students`, `Classes` and `StudentsInClasses`.

The Entity Framework translates these into two entities `Student` and `Class`, each linking to the other with a many-to-many navigation property (e.g. `Student.Classes`).

But there is no `StudentsInClasses` entity, so **what's the best way to call, using LINQ to Entities, the equivalent of SQL**:

```
DELETE FROM StudentsInClasses;
```

I definitely want to avoid loading all `Classes` and their `Students`. Of course I could do it that way, but that would be horrendous because there are thousands of them and there should be no need.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't like executing a store command like Paperjam suggested you could also create a stored procedure for this. That would nicely map to a static typed function on your ObjectContext.

Answer (score 3):

First: As far as I know, you can't delete data using EF without first loading that data.

Secondly: you can use ADO or POCO (above EF.4):

```
 try
        {
            using (testEntities db = new testEntities())
            {                    
                db.ExecuteStoreCommand<returnClass>("DELETE FROM StudentsInClasses;", NULL);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { _Exceptions.ManageExceptions(ex);}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Student.Class.Clear()
```

It's that simple! Just save changes and the Many-to-Many table will be free of entries for that student.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a doubt on your EF mapping, you can check the metadata file. These file are usually present in the directory `obj/Debug/edmxResourcesToEmbed` of your project. The metadata file `yourEntities.msl` defines the mapping between objects and tables.
In this file you should find that the `Students.Classes` is mapped on the `StudentInClasses` table, so removing entries in that list and saving the Students is equal to delete rows on the StudentInClasses table.