# Select all records from 2 tables - many-to-many EF C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, many-to-many

I have 2 tables in my MVC 5 application

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public DateTime? Birthdate { get; set; }
}

public class Movie
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
}
```

And joint table **Rentals** for many-to-many relationship

```
public class Rental
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Movie Movie { get; set; }

    public DateTime? DateReturned { get; set; }
}
```

Rental table looks like this when populated (just IDs from both Movie and Customer PKs):

[Table Rental](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p48n9.jpg)

How to select all records (just lets say customer name and all his movies) into one table from those 2 tables (or one joint Rental) in my  HomeController to View?

Comment: I let some more expret eyes judge if it's a dupe :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7800332/linq-to-entities-select-all-entries-in-many-to-many-relationship

Comment: I'm sure you tried something. Where specifically did you get stuck?

Comment: I wast stuck at the beginning. Didn't have any idea where to go from. I now added navigation property in Customer class like @lucky suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add navigation property (`ICollection<Rental> Rentals`) for `Customer` entity to represent `Rentals` entities.

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public DateTime? Birthdate { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Rental> Rentals { get; set; }
}
```

And query per customer for all movies;

```
var result = dbo.Customers.Select(x => new CustomerDto
{
    Name = x.Name,
    Movies = x.Rentals.Select(k => k.Movie)
});
```

Comment: It works, tnx!
I forgot navigation property, and have created **CustomerDto** class like this

    `public class CustomerDto
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
    }`